# Error de Reportes en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014, dataset

help

Hola, este Error ya me había salido en otro sistema que estaba desarrollando y realmente nunca di con el Error.

ME SALIO DE NUEVO EN ESTE SISTEMA.

Narrativa:

Estoy haciendo un reporte con una Vista la cual esta entrelazada con 3 Tablas, un WHERE y una de ella en un campo tiene un Alias:

SELECT Empenio.ID, Cliente.Nombre + ' ' + Cliente.Apellido Cliente , Cliente.Telefono, Garantia.Nombre AS Garantia,

Garantia.Marca, Garantia.Color, Empenio.Capital, Empenio.Taza, Empenio.Fecha

FROM Cliente INNER JOIN Empenio ON Cliente.ID = Empenio.IDCliente INNER JOIN Garantia ON Empenio.IDGarantia = Garantia.ID WHERE

Garantia.Estado ='EMPEÑADA'

Estoy utilizando VS2015, Hago el DataSet y el Informe en C# y todo Bien, pero cuando ejecuto, me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿puedes añadir el código donde manda a llamar las Textbox donde te sale el error?

Comment: #00FFFFFF... no te está sobrando un par de F's?